# Верна ли расстановка знаков препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

При взрослении наступает такой момент, когда личности предстоит переосмыслить определенные события, повлиявшие на нее, – будь они травматичными, радостными или просто незабываемыми, вот девушка и рассудила: «<...>».

Comment: Не бывает многоточия с запятой вместе. Если ставят многоточие, то не важно, какой бы знак был без него. То же касается и двоеточия, разумеется.

Comment: многоточие в данном случае для того чтобы отметить неполную приведенность фрагмента текста. меня конкретно интересует тире перед "будь" и запятая перед "вот и"

Comment: Чтобы ответить на Ваши вопросы, надо видеть полное предложение.

Comment: не думаю. но приведу полное: «при взрослении наступает такой момент, когда личности предстоит переосмыслить определенные события, повлиявшие на нее, – будь они травматичными, радостными или просто незабываемыми, вот и девушка рассудила:«<...>»

Comment: Ну вот. Как же не надо? Появился причастный оборот и другие слова. Всё на всё влияет. Хорошо бы  это включить в поле вопроса. // А часто даже полного предложения недостаточно, нужен контекст, окружение...

Comment: да... спасибо, изменила.

Comment: А ещё момент. *"вот **и девушка** рассудила"* – именно такой порядок слов нужен? Здесь как будто получается так, что сначала кто-то думал-рассуждал, а сейчас ещё и девушка подключилась. Может, нужен такой смысл: *"вот девушка **и рассудила**"*?

Comment: да, все так: «вот девушка и рассудила»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы написала так (предлагается в качестве **варианта**):

*При взрослении наступает такой момент, когда человеку предстоит переосмыслить определенные события, повлиявшие на него, – **будь они травматичными, радостными или просто незабываемыми**, – вот девушка и рассудила: «<...>».*

**Пояснение**

1. Лучше использовать **вставную** конструкцию с двумя тире, так как предложение выглядит как **дополнительное** пояснение, в том числе с точки зрения интонации и грамматики.
2. **Первая** запятая закрывает придаточное, а **вторая** обозначает структуру предложения.
3. **Замена** слова "личность" связана с повтором форм ж. рода.: личность, она, девушка. (Это на усмотрение автора.)

Comment: Параллельно вам писал ответ... :)) Да, тоже добавил бы второе тире. Только написал бы, что запятая перед первым тире закрывает причастный оборот, а перед вторым – всё придаточное, так как вставка по смыслу относится к нему.

Comment: Спасибо за голос! ("Тихо" пишете, как в нашей пословице:))  А я  не собиралась отвечать, просто прочитала предложение в обновленном вашими стараниями виде и решила, что одного тире не хватит) Запятые? Там так много условий для постановки двух запятых, что мне показалось: не так важно, что они обозначают.  И так сойдет)